# Storing arrays in database : JSON vs. serialized array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, json

With ruby-on-rails, I want to store an array of 3 elements: the last 3 comments of a post. I know I could join the Comment table to the Post one, but I would avoid to do this heavy request for scaling purposes.

So I was wondering what was the best way to store those 3 elements, as I would like to update them easily every time a new comment is made: remove the last comment and add the new one.

What is the correct way to do this ? Store it in a serialized array or in a JSON object ?

Comment: If you're on postgres, it has array column type.

Comment: I'm using postgres : you recommend using their array column type ?

Comment: Obviously. Why would you want to mess with JSON, if you have arrays.

Comment: I'm using Rails 3.2 and it doesn't seem to support that function of PG

Comment: @titibouboul It is a good practice to add your stack details especially rails and ruby version in question by default. It saves a lot of your time and experienced people can answer better and faster (:

Answer (score 96, accepted):

You can store Arrays and Hashes using ActiveRecord's `serialize` declaration:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :stuff
end

comment = Comment.new  # stuff: nil
comment.stuff = ['some', 'stuff', 'as array']
comment.save
comment.stuff # => ['some', 'stuff', 'as array']
```

You can specify the class name that the object type should equal to (in this case `Array`). This is more explicit and a bit safer. You also won't have to create the array when you assign the first value, since you'll be able to append to the existing (empty) array.

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :stuff, Array
end

comment = Comment.new  # stuff: []
comment.stuff << 'some' << 'stuff' << 'as array'
```

You can even use a neater version called store: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Store.html

This should handle your use case using a built in method.

Comment: Once an Array is serialized, how do you extract it from the database? I THINK the last line of this answer might be referring to that, but I'm not sure. If there's a built-in method for de-serializing an Array, what is it?

Comment: Yes the last line is doing that. It is automatically serialized and de serialized under the hood.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As a Rails noobie, I'm asking you to spell out how that's done 'above the hood'.

Comment: OK, I think I see what you mean. The last line of CODE does the de serializing. I hope you don't mind, but NOW I'm wondering where I would put the Comment class for a Rails project. Does it belong in the controllers folder?

Comment: There's a number of ways to (de)serialize manually. Look into YAML.dump, Marshall.dump, and JSON. For a more thorough answer I suggest posting a question than to so this in the comments. I'll be glad to elaborate if you link me to your question.

Comment: Is Comment a model? Those go in the models folder.

Comment: I've asked a question here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25916449/saving-and-retrieving-an-array-in-rails

Comment: I'm guessing the `stuff` field would be of type string when stubbing out the model?

Comment: To answer my own question, a type of `string` or `text` would work for this example, though `text` should be preferred since you don't want to accidentally run into the max length limit.