# Active admin / Carrierwave multiple image upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, activeadmin, multi-upload

I've been struggling for a week now, I'm trying to create a form inside active_admin where a user can select several pictures, add a description and a title, then submitting his form to create something that would look like a gallery

So far, I have two models created with the commands:

```
rails g model Gallery title:string description:text
rails g model Image url:text #just in case the user has LOTS of images to upload
```

Here are how look my models now:

**gallery.rb**

```
class Gallery < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :images
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :images, allow_destroy: true
end
```

**image.rb**

```
class Image < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :gallery
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader #Using Carrier Wave
end
```

**admin/gallery.rb**

```
  permit_params :title, :description, :images

  form html: { multipart: true }  do |f|
    f.inputs  do
      f.input :title
      f.input :description
      f.input :images, as: :file, input_html: { multiple: true }
    end
    f.actions
  end
```

My problem is that even though my 'image' form shows up, I can't manage to save the images through the other model, nothing gets uploaded inside my 'public/upload' directory, and nothing gets written inside my database.

I can't find anything interesting internet that could solve this problem

Feel free to ask for another file

Any help welcome

Comment: You can solve your problem by changing `permit_params` call (**admin/gallery.rb**):
`permit_params :title, :description, images_attributes: [:image]`
Hope, it helps

Answer (score 3):

> permit_params :title, :description, :images

Why **:images**, I think you meant **images_attributes: [:url]**?

But that wouldn't work either. I followed the steps here: https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/issues/1653#issuecomment-121248254

You can do it with just one model

```
rails g model Gallery title:string description:text url:string
```

models/gallery.rb

```
# your url is accepted as an array, that way you can attach many urls
serialize :url, Array
mount_uploaders :url, ImageUploader
```

> Note: Use serialize with Sqlite, For Postgres or some other database capable of handling arrays read: [Add an array column in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32409820/add-an-array-column-in-rails)

admin/gallery.rb

```
permit_params :title, :description, url: []
form html: { multipart: true }  do |f|
  f.inputs  do
    f.input :title
    f.input :description
    f.input :url, as: :file, input_html: { multiple: true }
  end
  f.actions
end
```