# Rails 4.0 save arrays and strings to single column

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to save data from a dynamic form where the response saved can be either an array, or a string.

Using serialize in my model or using ':question_answer => []' in my permit tries to set every entry as an array. I need this to dynamically allow saving either as a string or an array to the MySQL DB.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate question with a good answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21315340/260670

Answer (score 0):

it's never a good way to save arrays in one column/field

better you make relations model/table with has and belongs to many

see here for more
[Save PHP array to MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978438/save-php-array-to-mysql)

here are the example that you can follow from railscasts

http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes-revised

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised (about questions and answers too)

Comment: My array is coming from a select field on a form with multiple: true

Looking at those videos, they seem focused on the has and belongs to many aspect for the creation of the survey, not the response?