# Storing a serialized array in the database an anti pattern? Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, activerecord, serialization, anti-patterns

As specified in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21312278/storing-arrays-in-database-json-vs-serialized-array) you can store serialized data in the database. What i want to know is if i really should or just create a simple extra table.

Object has a list of asociated numbers.

Will probably need to check if an object has a particular number.

Will never update it.

Wont query it.

Have property numbers as serialize?

Have table Numbers belonging to Objects?

BTW im using rails 5.1 and postgresql.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using PostgreSQL, you actually have a third option: use an array column.

Add the `array: true` option when creating the column:

```
t.integer :column_name, array: true
```

and then `model.column_name` will be a Ruby array and you can use all the [PostgreSQL array operators and functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html) to work with and query the array.

I tend to think that you're usually better off with a separate table but an array column is often convenient and fairly easy to unroll into a separate table if necessary.

I'd stay away from `serialize`. That throws a blob of YAML into your database and YAML is difficult and cumbersome to query let alone manipulate inside the database.

Comment: Yes, accidental submit. Thanks. I deleted my answer and will delete this comment as well.