# Sequel and Postgres array of enum

Tags: arrays, ruby, postgresql, enums, sequel-gem

I have `enum_cars`.

I have table `user` with column: `own_cars:  enum_cars[]`

When I get User model and fetch `own_cars` field for instance, I have:

```
user.own_cars #=> "{Ford}" String
```

I connected

> DB.extension :pg_array

and

> Sequel.extension :pg_array

But this doesn't work for me. What I should do to fetch field as `Array`? Or it's impossible with enum array?

Comment: Are you asking how to [store arrays in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21312278/storing-arrays-in-database-json-vs-serialized-array)? Or are you not familiar with `has_many`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolve this problem.

If you have in table array enum field u should registrate array type:

```
DB.extension :pg_array
DB.register_array_type(:enum_cars)
```