# Set model attribute to be an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, database, model, rails-activerecord

Following some other StackOverflow questions and other articles on the web, I was trying to add an array attribute to one of my models.

> rails g migration add_new_attribute_to_my_model new_attribute:text

Then in the migration file

```
def change
  add_column :my_model, :new_attribute, :text, default: [].to_yaml
end
```

*(because if I do*

```
def change
  add_column :my_model, :new_attribute, :text, default: [], array:true
end
```

*I get `TypeError: can't quote Array`in the migration).*

> rake db:migrate

In `my_model_controller.rb`

```
class MyModelController < ApplicationController

  class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
    serialize :new_attribute,Array
  end

  ...

end
```

But like this I get

> a = MyModel.new
>   =>MyModel ... new_attribute: "--- []\n">
>   a.new_attribute << "asd"
>   =>MyModel ... new_attribute: "--- []\nasd">

Where should I fix the process?

Comment: Have you see this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21312278/storing-arrays-in-database-json-vs-serialized-array

Comment: If you're defining MyModel with the serializer inside of MyModelController, then the way you'd refer to it in Rails console is MyModelController::MyModel.New. Do you have a second copy of MyModel some place (such as app/models) that does not include your serializer code?

Comment: Which database are you using? Some support array columns, some require `serialize` and YAML hackery to emulate arrays.

Comment: @gwalshington yes but It didn't help.
@bkimble when doing `MyModelController::MyModel.New` it's working fine! What would be the best way to achieve that by just doing `MyModel.new`?

Comment: @bkimble achieved by placing the `serialize` in app/models/my_model`. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. You shouldn't ever be storing ActiveRecord model code inside your Controllers ;) (almost) Everything has its place in Rails.