# Rails 5 - Empty Array is not serialized to NULL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

According to the Rails 5 [documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.2/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html) an empty Array should be serialized to NULL:

> Empty objects as {}, in the case of Hash, or [], in the case of Array, will always be persisted as null.

Maybe I got it wrong but my empty Array is always serialized as --- [] (YAML) or [] (JSON) in the database. Beside that, the serialization works fine and as expected.

I am asking because we are currently running Rails 4 but we may want to switch to Rails 5. But then the behavior would change from [] to NULL (since the sentence above is missing in Rails 4 documentation). Therefore I thought of writing my own serializer for Rails 4 that also uses NULL instead of [], but it looks like as if this is not necessay.

For completeness:

```
class TestModel < ActiveRecord::Base  
    serialize :test_attribute, JSON #doesn't matter if it's JSON, Hash or YAML
end

TestModel.create(test_attribute: [])
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21315340/10522579)

Comment: I don't really see why you would want to use `serialize` today if you are using a decent db like Postgres. Use native JSON type columns instead which are handled by the driver.

Comment: Seem to be having the same problem

Comment: Can you post your JSON serializer class definition?

Comment: @DustinK We are using rails default serialize class https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/serialize/class